# Thermodynamics - Equations of State

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

How do we calculate the entropy and the enthalpy of compression of R-143a from 1.5 MPa to 5 MPa at 383.15 K giving the following information:

At 1.5 to 5 Mpa and 353.15 to 403.15 K, the compound 1,1,1-trifluoroethane (Refrigerant R-143a) follows the equation of state:

[image]

Comment: I started by calculating the Vm by substituting the pressure and temperature given, but after that I'm not sure what equation I need to use.

Comment: What are the fundamental equations for the partial derivatives of entropy and enthalpy with respect to pressure at constant temperature?  And, in your equation, what does Vm stand for?

Comment: I used ∆S=nR ln⁡(V_2/V_1 ) = -10.01 J/K

Comment: That's not valid for your gas, except at low pressures.  In the range of this data, it is not valid.

Comment: This gas does not satisfy the Van Der Waals equation of state either.  They gave you the equation of state.  Just use what they gave you.  See the very next thread after yours in the Thermodynamics questions:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590701/validity-of-maxwell-relations. Also, you still haven't told me what Vm stands for.  Specific volume?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115697/discussion-between-helpmeplease-and-chet-miller).

Comment: It's the molar volume

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

Comment: this is awesome